# Woocommerce category page display this custom field before products

Tags: php, woocommerce

The code bellow, is to show a custom field I created to customize Woocommerce product category pages.. This code makes the custom field appear "after" the list of products. I need to make this code appear BEFORE the list of products... any hint on what I have to change in this bit of php code to make the custom field show before?

```
<?php
// Display details on product category archive pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'wpm_product_cat_archive_add_meta' );
function wpm_product_cat_archive_add_meta() {
$t_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
$term_meta_content = $term_meta['custom_term_meta'];
if ( $term_meta_content != '' ) {
echo '<div class="woo-sc-box normal rounded full">';
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $term_meta_content );
echo '</div>';
}
}
```

Thank you, I would really like to understand what makes the code appear after and not before, is the filter? in the last lines?

I found this bit of code at http://www.wpmusketeer.com/add-a-wysiwyg-field-to-woocommerce-product-category-page/

Answer (score 0):

use below action to display custom fields before list of products
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop','wpm_product_cat_archive_add_meta');

Comment: works like a charm, thanks now I understand more about the add_action command !